# Migradoc - Tables Side by Side - not using Tables within Tables

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am using Migradoc and wish to replicate a table structure as follows:

[image]

What I really DON'T want to do is add each table into a cell of a larger table with 2 columns and 2 rows... Mainly because i) the number of tables generated can vary so it needs to be more dynamic and ii) Adding tables within tables can cause issues when spilling across to the next page.

What I had initially hoped is that I could just keep adding each new table to a TextFrame and the tables will be added horizontally and wrap to the next page if the next table wouldn't fit... Of course, not that straight forward. So far the closest I have come to even seeing a Table next to another one is with the following:

```
TextFrame newTF = new TextFrame
{
    Width = Unit.FromPoint(200)
};
WrapFormat wf = new WrapFormat();
wf.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
newTF.WrapFormat = wf;
newTF.Add(newTable.Clone());
this.document.LastSection.Add(newTF);

TextFrame newTF2 = new TextFrame
{
    Width = Unit.FromPoint(200)
};
WrapFormat wf2 = new WrapFormat();
wf2.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
newTF2.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
newTF2.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Paragraph;
newTF2.Left = ShapePosition.Right;
newTF2.WrapFormat = wf2;
newTF2.Add(newTable.Clone());
this.document.LastSection.Add(newTF2);
```

However this is very static and would require a new definition for each TextFrame. Plus, the layout doesn't look amazing as the second table ignores any margins set out in the page.

If what I am asking is at all possible, am I even on the correct path? I have been looking into this all morning and am starting to feel my options sllipping away! I would have thought this would be a big requirement for a lot of Migradoc users so am surprised to find it is tricky to do? Unless I am just missing something silly of course.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: create a table with 5 columns and set table borders to make it look like 2 tables with 2 columns each.

Depending on the data you add to the tables it might be better to use a table row for each line of text or have all text lines in a single row.

From your picture I assume that using a table with 2 columns and 1 row, each cell containing a table, would work, too, provided the visible tables are small enough to fit a single page.